# Is there a way to generate a supressions.xml file for checkstyle from the existing codebase?

Tags: java, legacy, checkstyle, legacy-code, suppress-warnings

I've got a legacy codebase that I'd like to add a full set of checkstyle checks to so that *going forward* the code codebase changes will comply to the checks.

I understand I'll have to put all the existing failures into a `supressions.xml` file. Is there a way to generate the `supressions.xml` file from the existing checkstyle failures report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now. Here is how to make Checkstyle run full throttle on a Legacy code base:
http://juliangamble.com/blog/2012/03/10/running-checkstyle-at-full-throttle-on-a-legacy-codebase/

(If you've got a problem that an open source tool doesn't solve - fix it yourself!)